# Constructing a simple 5x5 coordinate system in scheme with some basic properties

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm currently taking a course that serves as an introduction to programming and I'm working on an assignment where I have to create a simple game. As you can imagine it's not supposed to be anything spectacular, they're only having us do it to get familiar with programming in general. I'm currently in the process of figuring out how to construct the various worlds of my game. I want to associate every world with a 5x5 coordinate system where I have the ability to put an object in every point. I also want to create functions such that I can add and remove an object from a particular point. The problem is that I can't figure out a way to implement this into my game so I've come here looking for some ideas. How should I go about doing this? I believe I could probably store the contents of each point (x,y) in some long mcons type of list but it seems like a massive pain in the ass to go about it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this. One way is to use flat mutable storage. For a 5x5 board, make a 25-element vector. Then element at (column,row) can be accessed by the vector index `(+ column (* 5 row))`. Note you're indexing your rows and columns from `0` in this scenario.